# Kattis problem Yoda: passing 8 test cases but failing on the 9th

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am doing a Kattis problem called [Yoda](https://open.kattis.com/problems/yoda) using Java. My submission passes 8 tests, but the 9 gives a run time error. Kattis does not show the input or output for the submission tests.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kattis_yoda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        
        String s1 = "";
        String s2 = "";
        
        s1 = Integer.toString(num1);
        s2 = Integer.toString(num2);
        int l1 = s1.length();
        int l2 = s2.length();
        
        String res1 = "";
        String res2 = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length() && i < s2.length(); i++){
            
            char ch1 = s1.charAt(l1-1);
            char ch2 = s2.charAt(l2-1);
            
            int a = Character.getNumericValue(ch1);
            int b = Character.getNumericValue(ch2);
            
            if(a == b)
            {
                res1 = Integer.toString(a) + res1;
                res2 = Integer.toString(b) + res2;
            }
            else if(a > b)
                res1 = Integer.toString(a) + res1;
            else
                res2 = Integer.toString(b) + res2;
                
            l1 -= 1;
            l2 -= 1;
        }
        
        if(l1 > l2)
        {
            int temp = l1;
            for(int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
                
                char ch1 = s1.charAt(l1-1);
                
                int a = Character.getNumericValue(ch1);
                res1 = Integer.toString(a) + res1;
                l1 -= 1;
            }          
            l1 = temp;
        }
        if(l2 > l1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < l2; i++){
                
                char ch1 = s2.charAt(l2-1);
                
                int a = Character.getNumericValue(ch1);
                res2 = Integer.toString(a) + res2;
                l2 -= 1;
            }            
        }
        
        if(res1.length() != 0 && res2.length() != 0)
        {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(res1);
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(res2);
            System.out.println(num1);
            System.out.println(num2);
        }
        else if(res1.length() == 0 && res2.length() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("YODA");
            System.out.println("YODA");
        }
        else if(res1.length() == 0 && res2.length() != 0)
        {

            num2 = Integer.parseInt(res2);
            System.out.println("YODA");
            System.out.println(num2);
        }
        else
        {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(res1);
            System.out.println(num1);
            System.out.println("YODA");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve the question and run multiple tests of my own. I got the expected answers and even the given test cases were passes, but for some reason I am failing one of the test cases on the website.

What is the issue with my code?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete error (with full stack trace).

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve]. As written, it's unclear what tests you're referring to. Note that all relevant details need to be here, in your question, and not on an external site.

Comment: There are no stack traces for Kattis so this is probably about as much info as can be provided. The question could be improved by describing what has been done to try to debug, what test cases and edge cases you've considered, and/or a high-level description of the algorithm approach taken here.

Comment: The problem has to do with your `for(int i = 0; i < l1; i++){` loops. You're counting `i++` up to `l1` while also decrementing `l1 -= 1`, which will skip half of the numbers that should be dumped. Count one way or the other, not both at the same time. I voted to reopen. Please ping me if it's reopened and I'll write an answer.

Comment: @ggorlen please guild me in the question it has been reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, but there's a subtle bug that causes the code to fail when one or the other of the strings is longer than the other and has multiple characters that should be kept at the end. Here's the problem:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
    // ...
    l1 -= 1;
}
```

Here, the loop counts `i++` while also counting `l1--`. This causes the loop to terminate prematurely, skipping elements that you intended to process.

A better condition would be `while (l1 > 0) {}`, removing the `i` entirely and simply counting backwards from the current index down to 1.

Here's a test case that your code fails on:

```
33300
500
```

Expected output:

```
3300
500
```

But your code gives:

```
300
500
```

Explanation: the two 0s in both numbers match and are preserved, leaving 333 and 5. The 5 beats the 3, dropping the 3 out of the top string. At this point, the 500 string is out of numbers to look at, leaving two remaining 3s in the top number. These 3s should be kept, giving 3300 and 500.

Don't forget to fix the tail `l2` loop as well.

Once your code passes the tests, you can simplify it. Here's my solution, which combines all of the loops into one and uses `if`s to determine which strings have elements left to be processed:

> ```
> public class Yoda {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         var s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
>         String a = s.next(), b = s.next();
>         s.close();
>         String ra = "", rb = "";
>         int i = a.length() - 1, j = b.length() - 1;
>
>         for (; i >= 0 || j >= 0; i--, j--) {
>             int x = i < 0 ? -1 : Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(i));
>             int y = j < 0 ? -1 : Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(j));
>
>             if (x >= y) {
>                 ra = a.charAt(i) + ra;
>             }
>             if (y >= x) {
>                 rb = b.charAt(j) + rb;
>             }
>         }
>
>         System.out.println(
>             (ra.isEmpty() ? "YODA" : Integer.parseInt(ra)) + "\n" +
>             (rb.isEmpty() ? "YODA" : Integer.parseInt(rb)) + "\n"
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```